# php: how to get main key from multi-dimension array

Tags: php

Ii just realised that I don't know how to get the main key from a multi-dimension array.

Here is my dynamic generated array:

```
$tempArray = Array ( 
[2013-03-13 15:56:57] => Array ( [PROD] => product2 [RFID] => 0030313 ) 
[2013-03-08 14:11:51] => Array ( [PROD] => product1 [RFID] => 0020313 ) 
)
```

Now how to get the main key?? or the value of the `[2013-03-13 15:56:57]`?
example: `$FirstDate = [2013-03-13 15:56:57]`, so how to get and assign it?
Tested but error :-

```
$tempArray[0] : Undefined offset: 0...<br/>
$tempArray[0][0] : Undefined offset: 0...<br/>
```

Comment: Just the key for the first element?

Comment: Check [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) : `$keys = array_keys($tempArray); echo $keys[0]; // output [2013-03-13 15:56:57]`

Comment: What defines ***main***?

Comment: if you need this info like this you've created the array incorrectly

Comment: here is the work-around, thanks for [HamZa DzCyberDeV] re-assign a new array by using array_key(), example:: $tempArray2 = array_keys($tempArray); echo $tempArray2[0];

Comment: You can loop through them with php's [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). `foreach ($tempArray as $idx => $valArray) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 ways ?

### foreach

Using foreach and then breaking the loop after the first iteration:

```
foreach($tempArray as $key => $val){
    $primaryKey = $key;break;
}
echo $primaryKey;
```

### array_keys()

By using [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$keys = array_keys($tempArray);
$primaryKey = $keys[0];
echo $primaryKey;
```

### key()

By using [key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

```
$primaryKey = key($tempArray);
echo $primaryKey;
```

Comment: Thanks, i know foreach, but looking for new method/way/code for this. thanks. i learn 2 new methods today.